# Differentiate nginx behaviour depending on URL

Tags: django, http-headers, nginx

I have a Django application and I use nginx to serve static content. Unfortunately, all registered MIME types get displayed in client browser, while I would like to give an ability to download **the same content**, along with usual behaviour. Say, I have JPEG file under `/media/images/image01.jpg` and I want that nginx serves this file in usual way, with standard `image/jpeg` header, but additionally I want **the same** image to be served by nginx with `content-disposition: attachment` (effectively forcing content download) when accessed as, say, `/downloads/images/image01.jpg`. Anybody can suggest a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have the http_headers_module compiled in. (should be by default, if it isn't in the core)

Use "add_header    content-disposition attachment;"

I recommend using a url like "/download?file=/downloads/images/image01.jpg" combined with a rewrite rule to avoid some annoying bug later.

[Http Headers Module Documention](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersModule)

Comment: Why and how would you use URL with query parameters? To give the file with wrong file name for the user?

Comment: The reason for using a url with query parameters is to tell nginx to only force a download when using /download?file={filename} By using a rewrite rule properly you can add the header and still run through the rest of the rules in nginx's config.

Comment: It's possible to ommit the "file=" part of the url and use "/download?{filename}" instead. The format is arbitrary the goal is to somehow let nginx know you need a different header than normal.