# Link to download image instead of view image (CANT Change Content-Disposition Header)

Tags: django, image, http-headers, content-disposition, static-files

I have a Django app and all the static content is handled through NGINX.  I want to allow users to download a couple of static resources (photos) in their client by clicking on a link in the markup.

To make the link/resource downloadable, I know I could change the Content-Disposition.  Unfortunately, since all my static assets are being served through NGINX, this seems problematic.  I don't want to create a view just to change the Content-Disposition and make the image downloadable.

Is there anything that I can do here via jQuery or otherwise?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975648/how-to-set-content-disposition-attachment-via-javascript] short anwser: you can't do it with javascript.

Comment: Doh, really? So disappointing....

Comment: Ta da: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528431/differentiate-nginx-behaviour-depending-on-url An identical question! Wow.